# How to hide domain name from Active Directory users and groups (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: 20.04, samba

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 server joining an Active Directory domain via winbind. Every time a user is referenced in Linux commands, it appears as domain\user. I would like these outputs omit the domain part, because it only adds noise (that Linux system itself doesn't use but one  local account).

Example:

```
USERT38\pablo@audrey:/store/sam$ ll
total 175
drwxrwx---  9 USERT38\pablo USERT38\domain users     9 jun 17 15:29 ./
drw-r-xr-x  8 root          root                     8 jun  7 17:49 ../
drwxrwx--- 25 USERT38\pablo USERT38\finance_g_rw    38 jun 30 18:26 Administracion/
drwxrwx--- 12 USERT38\pablo USERT38\domain users    17 may 23 02:56 Cine/
drwxrwx---  3 USERT38\pablo USERT38\domain users     3 may 26 20:16 Eddie/
drwxrwx--- 14 USERT38\pablo USERT38\domain users    20 jun 17 14:22 Grafico/
drwxrwx---  6 USERT38\pablo USERT38\production_g_rw  8 jun  6 11:23 Presupuestos/
drwxrwx---  8 USERT38\pablo USERT38\domain users    14 abr 18 15:31 Publi/
```

I have another system in house using Centos 7 and it hides the "USERT38\" part, making it much cleaner and easier to read. But I can't find how it's done there (I don't administer that system).

Is there anything in smb.conf or any other config file that hides this redundant information in the CLI?

Answer (score 1):

Provided this isn't a Samba AD DC, or winbind is using 'autorid' for the idmap backend, then add 'winbind use default domain = yes' to the smb.conf. You may also need to flush the cache with 'net cache flush' or restart Samba.

Comment: Thanks. That did it.